# No puedo hacer que el ciclo while comience la función de nuevo si no se ha cumplido determinada condición

Tags: javascript, funciones, bucles, while

En este código trato de colocar el ciclo while de manera que vuelva a empezar si se ha excedido el límite de compra o si el usuario no ha sumado el valor mínimo de usdt pero no lo he conseguido. Intenté de distintas maneras pero me mareé tanto que el código empezó a perder su funcionamiento original y es por eso que coloco acá como se comenzó desde cero.

El window.reload hace su trabajo adecuadamente pero allí tengo una duda y no sé si en vez de colocar ese elemento, justamente allí es donde debería reiniciar el ciclo, en vez de solo recargar la página.

```
function comprar(){
    let compra1=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese USDT que desea comprar (Maximo 10.000 USDT)"));
    let compra2= compra1*257;
    if(compra1>10000){
        alert("Ha excedido el limite de compra.");
        location.reload()
    }else if(compra1<1){
        alert("Debe comprar al menos 1 USDT");
    }
    while((compra1>0)&&(compra1<10000)){
        alert("Total de compra en ARS: "+compra2+". Presione ACEPTAR para confirmar la compra.");
        alert("Gracias por tu compra!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque usas un while y no otro if, no necesitas un loop ya que no modificas el valor de compra. Podrías colocar la función dentro de un while para repetirla pero dentro de la función no tiene caso.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que hago es meter los 2 casos de errores **(si no se llega al mínimo o si se supera el máximo)** en un bucle del que no saldrá al menos que el usuario introduzca un numero valido, recién cuando se cumple la condición de que `compra1 > 0 y < 10000` se pasa a las otras 2 líneas donde se confirma la compra.
Espero que te sirva.

Te comparto mi solución:

```
function comprar(){
let compra1;
let compra2;
do{
     compra1=parseInt(prompt("Ingrese USDT que desea comprar (Maximo 10.000 USDT)"));
     compra2= compra1*257;
     if(compra1>10000) alert("Ha excedido el limite de compra.");
     else if(compra1<1) alert("Debe comprar al menos 1 USDT");
}while((compra1<=0) || (compra1>10000));
     alert("Total de compra en ARS: "+compra2+". Presione ACEPTAR para confirmar la compra.");
     alert("Gracias por tu compra!");
}
    
comprar();
```